How to set cursor width and color in Windows Terminal
I'm trying to customize the cursor in Windows Terminal by setting the cursor width and color. Does anyone have an idea how to get this to work?
I've edited the settings.json file as follows:
{
    "profiles": {
        "defaults": {
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",      // Cursor color
            "cursorShape": "bar",          // Cursor shape
            "cursorHeight": 50,            // Height percentage for bar or underscore shape
            "cursorThickness": 2,          // Thickness for filledBox or emptyBox shape
            // other settings
        },
        "list": [
            {
                "name": "Command Prompt",
                "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
                "cursorShape": "bar",
                "cursorHeight": 50,
                "cursorThickness": 2,
                // other settings
            }
        ]
    }
}

